# how to block any request to my api-gateway url based on domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have 2 setup,

```
1) Cloud-Front -> Api-Gateway -> Lambda 
2) Cloud-Front -> S3 bucket (enabled web server) -> static UI files
```

Now is there any way to block my 1st cloud front url to allow request only from my UI cloud-front domain name? i.e If the browser is making a backend api call then it should work. But if the same api call is made from POSTMAN / CURL outside of browser then it should be blocked.
I tried enabling CORS with specific domain name, it is not blocking the request when we do from "Curl"

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to setup WAF for your CF domain to filter incoming requests using `Referer` header. This process is explained in:

- [How to Prevent Hotlinking by Using AWS WAF, Amazon CloudFront, and Referer Checking](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-by-using-aws-waf-amazon-cloudfront-and-referer-checking/)

You could also do the same with using [lambda@edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html) or [CF functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html), if you don't want to use WAF.